# Is there a known linux kernel bug with two threads incorrectly getting back the same file descriptor number?

Tags: linux, kernel, file-descriptors

I've got a multithreaded program in which a sem_open with O_CREAT occasionally fails with EBADF.  This is on an ARM linux 4.9.88, from NXP, on an embedded device.

It is very difficult to reproduce, but I did catch a situation with strace, where it looks like two threads are receiving the same file descriptor (one for openat() inside sem_open, and one as the read end returned from pipe2) when creating a file and a pipe at the same time.

Strace (pid 266 is the thread calling sem_open, and pid 268 is another thread calling popen) reported:

```
[pid   266] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/shm/pPC113", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0777 <unfinished ...>
[pid   268] close(12)                   = 0
[pid   268] mq_timedreceive(10, "\0\0\0\0\1g\7\0", 8, NULL, NULL) = 8
[pid   266] <... openat resumed> )      = 12
[pid   268] pipe2([12, 13], O_CLOEXEC)  = 0
```

Note that both openat() and pipe2() are returning descriptor 12, when they should be returning different descriptors.

Later on, sem_open attempts to write to descriptor 12, and receives EBADF, presumably because descriptor 12 is the read end of a pipe rather than the file it created.

This seems like a clear kernel bug to me; open and pipe are both returning the same file descriptor.  Does anyone know if this is a known bug with a fix in a later kernel?

Comment: I work on mm, so not completely the same area as the problem you're having, but it seems much more likely you have an issue elsewhere. If this was the case you'd end up with so many applications affected that it would be blatantly obvious, and no distribution would ever ship that version unpatched.

Comment: @ChrisDown it is very rare and timing dependent, even when I'm trying to make it happen.  My kernel is also fairly old.  It is rare enough that if I upgrade the kernel and it goes away, I won't really know it's been fixed.  So I am hoping to locate an actual fix that addressed it.
Finally, what issue could I have that could cause two threads to receive back the same descriptor at the same time for different streams?

Comment: If the kernel is "fairly old", then even if there is a bug it might have been fixed. Try the latest Linux.